# How do I get detailed logging when I run a single test in Gradle?

Tags: debugging, testing, logging, gradle, command-line

I'm trying to find out why a single test is failing in my build, so I know I need to run gradle with the tests flag like so:

```
./gradlew test --tests com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod
```

However I wanted to see some trace logs so I had more detailed information on what my test was doing. I know that the options for seeing more detailed logs are --stacktrace, --info, and --debug. So normally, to see more detailed logging on all tests, I'd use the following:

```
`./gradlew test --debug` or `./gradlew test -d`
```

In this case, ***I'd like to only see debug logs for myTestMethod***, but none of my attempts are working. I always get debug logs for ALL of the tests; it's running ALL of the tests instead of the single one I specify. I've tried the following combinations, all to no avail:

**With --debug**

Appended at the end:
`./gradlew test --tests com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod --debug`

Appended at the end with quotes around the tests param: `./gradlew test --tests "com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod" --debug`

Appended before tests flag: `./gradlew test --debug --tests com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod`

Appended before tests flag with tests param in quotes: `./gradlew test --debug --tests "com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod"`

**With -d**

Appended at the end:
`./gradlew test --tests com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod -d`

Appended at the end with quotes around the tests param: `./gradlew test --tests "com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod" -d`

Appended before tests flag: `./gradlew test -d --tests com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod`

Appended before tests flag with tests param in quotes: `./gradlew test -d --tests "com.myname.myproject.mypackage.MyTestClass.myTestMethod"`

***Is there something I'm doing wrong?***

*Gradle version used in wrapper:* 2.14.1

*Note:* I'm also setting up some environment variables before the command, specifically, spring boot profiles. I'm thinking that shouldn't affect anything as it's not part of the gradle command, but I figured I'd state so just in case. So in reality, all of the commands I'm running look more like this: `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile1,profile2 ./gradlew test ...`

Comment: Are you ever able to execute just the one single test? That is, does your first command up above work as expected?

Comment: Yes. With JUST the tests option, I'm able to run just the single test specified. As soon as I add a logging option, it's like gradle ignores the tests option completely and always runs all the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Test output is written to files. Look into `build/reports` and `build/test-results`.

Comment: Yes, but unless I'm missing something, the report doesn't include any detailed logging... just the standard output.

Comment: What kind of detailed logging do you expect? If you use a logger configure it to write to the console.

Comment: I did. I'm using spring boot and have the following logging settings in my application.properties (new lines delineated by 'AND'):

logging.pattern.console=%d | %p | %50C{50}:%L - %m%n
AND
logging.level.root=WARN
AND
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=TRACE